# Echo with new line from fun()

Tags: erlang

*I've recently been trying to get to grips with Erlang, but am slightly confused by this...*

#### Problem

I am trying to write a function object in the shell, which receives any message and echoes it back to the shell followed by a new line.

#### Attempt

My attempt at the function is:

```
Echo = fun() -> receive Any -> io:fwrite(Any), io:fwrite("~n") end end.
```

However, if I spawn a new process for this...

```
someNode@someHost 2> Pid = spawn(Echo).
<0,76,0>
```

...and then send it a message...

```
someNode@someHost 3> Pid ! "Hello".
Hello"Hello"
```

...I don't seem to get a new line character after the write, and before the message return.

#### Question

Is there something wrong with my approach, that stops this (very simple) example working as expected?

*Thanks in advance*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is atomicity.
After printing the first line, the "main thread" gets scheduled and prints the result of `Pid ! Msg`, i.e. `Msg`.

[io:fwrite](http://erldocs.com/R14B04/stdlib/io.html?i=4&search=fwri#fwrite/3) can take arguments just like printf in C:

```
Echo = fun() ->
    receive
        Any ->
            io:fwrite("~p~n", [Any])
    end
end
```

Comment: I really should have noticed that sooner- having used the "~p" approach multiple times before. I blame it being a morning. Thanks, spot on answer :)